# Vb.net Generic Function cannot convert type T

Tags: vb.net, generics

I have the following function to return a string of hex values to make up a packet of data, but the value can be a byte, UShort, Integer, Single, or a String.

```
Public Function GetWriteString(ByVal op As Operation, ByVal value As UShort) As String
    Dim dataString As String = DATA_CONST & WRITE_CONST & op.ToString(Operation.Accessibility.WRITE) & ToHex(value)
    Dim byteCount As String = ToHex(GetByteCount(dataString))
    Return headerString & byteCount & CRC_Module.HeaderCRC(headerString & byteCount) & dataString & CRC_Module.DataCRC(dataString)
End Function
```

I want to make the function a generic function because it is always the same, the only difference is the `ToHex(value)` portion. The `ToHex` Function is an overloaded function for each of the data types specified above, so it will return a different string depending on the value. When I try to make the function generic,

```
Public Function GetWriteString(Of T)(ByVal op As Operation, ByVal value As T) As String
    Dim dataString As String = DATA_CONST & WRITE_CONST & op.ToString(Operation.Accessibility.WRITE) & ToHex(value)
    Dim byteCount As String = ToHex(GetByteCount(dataString))
    Return headerString & byteCount & CRC_Module.HeaderCRC(headerString & byteCount) & dataString & CRC_Module.DataCRC(dataString)
End Function
```

it says "Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'ToHex' can be called with these arguments:
Public Function ToHex(hex as Byte) as String: Value of type 'T' cannot be converted to 'Byte'" and so on for each of the overloaded `ToHex` functions. Is there a way to make this function generic, and if so, is this the best way to go about it, or should I create 5 different functions explicitly stating each data type in the parameters for the function?

ToHex Functions:

```
Public Function ToHex(ByVal characters As String) As String
    ' Variables
    ' byteArray - An array of bytes used to hold the characters which were converted to bytes
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = defaultEncoding.GetBytes(characters)
    ' Converts the byte array to a string of hex values
    Return BitConverter.ToString(byteArray).Replace("-", "")
End Function

Public Function ToHex(ByVal hex As Byte) As String
    Return hex.ToString("X2")
End Function

Public Function ToHex(ByVal word As UShort) As String
    Return word.ToString("X4")
End Function

Public Function ToHex(ByVal int As Integer) As String
    Return int.ToString("X8")
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Converts a float to a string of hex bytes
''' </summary>
''' <param name="float">A float value to be converted</param>
''' <returns>A string of hex bytes</returns>
Public Function ToHex(ByVal float As Single) As String
    ' Variables
    ' byteArray - An array of bytes used to hold the bytes that make up the floating point
    Dim byteArray = defaultEncoding.GetBytes(float)
    ' Reverses the byte array
    Array.Reverse(byteArray)
    ' Converts the byte array to a string of hex values
    Return BitConverter.ToString(byteArray).Replace("-", "")
End Function
```

Comment: I think own overload for every type will be more clearer and maintainable approach.

Comment: What is `ToHex`?  Is that a built-in function, or something you wrote?  You'll need to make it generic as well., or simply have it accept `Object`. Not sure that using generics here is all that useful.

Comment: If you continue to use generic then your `ToHex` method need to use `If` or `Select` statements to decide which type is passed and execute correspondent method

Comment: the ToHex function is also a function I wrote, i guess I'll just use overload for each then since using if or select inside a generic function kind of defeats the purpose in the first place, plus it will be more readable as overloaded functions

Comment: You could make ToHex a generic function as well, although you should really constrain both generic function to numeric types.

Comment: **1.** *...the value can be a byte, UShort, Integer, Single, or a String.* Can't constrain the generic to numeric types (not that you could do that easily anyway). **2.** Your ability to make it generic relies heavily on what is inside ToHex(). You should paste that in your question. .NET does something similar with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.getbytes(v=vs.110).aspx, and even this isn't generic.

Comment: @Verdolino I edited the question showing the ToHex function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make your ToHex function take an Object. This is the only way to have a single function across all primitive types, because all the primitive types only share one common base type: object. This doesn't work on DateTime, but you could add a case for it. Note: you can pass *anything* to this function, so it's not really a good idea to have it in your project. But it should accomplish what you wanted at least.

```vb
Option Strict Off
```

---

```vb
<Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension>
Public Function ToHex(input As Object) As String
    Dim defaultEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default
    Dim result As String
    Dim byteArray As Byte()
    If TypeOf (input) Is String Then
        byteArray = defaultEncoding.GetBytes(input)
        result = BitConverter.ToString(byteArray).Replace("-", "")
    Else
        Dim byteCount = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(input)
        If (TypeOf (input) Is Single) OrElse (TypeOf (input) Is Double) OrElse (TypeOf (input) Is Decimal) Then
            byteArray = BitConverter.GetBytes(input)
            Array.Reverse(byteArray)
            result = BitConverter.ToString(byteArray).Replace("-", "").PadLeft(byteCount * 2, "0")
        Else
            result = CLng(input).ToString("X").PadLeft(byteCount * 2, "0")
        End If
    End If
    Return result
End Function
```

Testing this:

```vb
Console.WriteLine("Single: " & Single.MaxValue.ToHex())
Console.WriteLine("Single: " & 1.0F.ToHex())

Console.WriteLine("Integer: " & Integer.MaxValue.ToHex())
Console.WriteLine("Integer: " & 1I.ToHex())
Console.WriteLine("Integer: " & 1I.ToString("X8"))

Console.WriteLine("UShort: " & UShort.MaxValue.ToHex())
Console.WriteLine("UShort: " & 1US.ToHex())
Console.WriteLine("UShort: " & 1US.ToString("X4"))

Console.WriteLine("String: " & "String".ToHex())
```

> Single: 7F7FFFFF
>   
> Single: 3F800000
>   
> Integer: 7FFFFFFF
>   
> Integer: 00000001
>   
> Integer: 00000001
>   
> UShort: FFFF
>   
> UShort: 0001
>   
> UShort: 0001
>   
> String: 537472696E67

If you don't want to extend Object, you can remove the `<Extension>` and just call it like `ToHex(Single.MaxValue)`

See why we can't accomplish exactly what you want here https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=numeric+generic+C%23

Comment: This code did not seem to work for me for data which has leading zeros, I need the leading zeros to work. For example, when the value 8 is passed as a UShort, the string returned is just "8", I need "0008", however, if it is passed as a byte,  I need "08" returned

Comment: OK what is the logic for the number of leading 0s?

Comment: For a byte type, I need 1 byte in hex (00) for a UShort, I need 2 Bytes (0000), For Integer and Single, I  need 4 Bytes (00000000) and For String I need one byte per character

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of case (or what I understand of it) I would put the common stuff in it's own (private) method and just call that with the right "hexed" value from the public ones.
This way you move the core code apart and the duplicated code is simple you can't bypass it *(look at how the BCL Team made the different overload for Enumerable.Max for exemple)*

```
Public Function GetWriteString(op As Operation, value As UShort) As String
    Return GetWriteStringInternal(op, ToHex(value))
End Function

Public Function GetWriteString(op As Operation, value As Byte) As String
    Return GetWriteStringInternal(op, ToHex(value))
End Function

Public Function GetWriteString(op As Operation, value As Integer) As String
    Return GetWriteStringInternal(op, ToHex(value))
End Function

Public Function GetWriteString(op As Operation, value As Single) As String
    Return GetWriteStringInternal(op, ToHex(value))
End Function

Public Function GetWriteString(op As Operation, value As String) As String
    Return GetWriteStringInternal(op, ToHex(value))
End Function

Private Function GetWriteStringInternal(op As Operation, hexValue As String) As String
    Dim dataString As String = DATA_CONST & WRITE_CONST & op.ToString(Operation.Accessibility.WRITE) & hexValue
    Dim byteCount As String = ToHex(GetByteCount(dataString)) ' Call the Integer overload if I've understood
    Return headerString & byteCount & CRC_Module.HeaderCRC(headerString & byteCount) & dataString & CRC_Module.DataCRC(dataString)
End Function
```

*As a side note the ToHex overload for Single don't work for me (probably related to Option Strict being On for me)*